# Jquery Autocomplete Select event was not working

Tags: jquery

I have a text box which implements jquery autocomplete. I am using controller and action to load the auto complete. On selection of a value i want the value to be loaded to another textbox. I used select event but it is not giving me the result. I have attached my code snippet. kindly help me to resolve the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#customer").autocomplete('/UserAdd/ClientList',
        {
            dataType: 'json',
            parse: function (data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i],value: data[i].AccountNumber, result: data[i].Name };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
                return row.Name;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#ClientName').val = ui.item.result;
            },
            width: 300,
            highlight: false,
            multiple: true,
            multipleSeparator: ","
       });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.val()` wrong:

```
$('#ClientName').val(ui.item.result);
```

See [jQuery's documentation on .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$('#ClientName').val = ui.item.result;` from select function and it will be like this

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
        }
```

Then use the following code that calls when you select value in customer:

```
$( "#customer" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
      var customer = $("customer").val(); //getting customer name
      $("#ClientName").val(customer);     //setting the client name
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the way you have recommended but still i am not getting the output. For testing purpose i placed an alert - that is also not popping up.

Comment: sorry! i forget '#' now try like this var customer = $("#customer").val(); on second line